# Beginner JavaScript - Car Colors

Tags: javascript, colors

"Modify the car-painting example so that the car is painted with your favorite color if you have one; otherwise it is painted w/ the color of your garage (if the color is known); otherwise it is painted red."
Car-painting example: 
car.color = favoriteColor || "black";

**How or what do I need to do to make my script work?**

```
car.color = favoriteColor || "red";
if (car.color = favoriteColor ){ 
    alert("your car is " + favoriteColor);

} else if (car.color = garageColor){
    alert("your car is " + garageColor);

} else {
    car.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: You need to declare the variable `favoriteColor`

Comment: your = operator... that's an assignment operator. You are trying to test for equality. Try == in the if statements

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/289478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the correct answer to your question:**

See my comments to get a better understanding of how this works.

```
if (favoriteColor) {
  car.color = favoriteColor; // If you have a favorite color, choose the favorite color.
} else if (garageColor) {
  car.color = garageColor;   // If the garage color is known, choose the garage color.
} else {
  car.color = 'red';         // Otherwise, choose the color 'red'.
}

alert('Your car is: ' + car.color);
```

**[Try it Online!](https://jsfiddle.net/jem6wp11/9/)**

**Related Question (for further insight):**

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/289475

**Alternative Method:**

As another possibility, you can write a [conditional (ternary) operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to compact all of the logic into a single statement.

```
alert('Your car is: ' + (car.color = favoriteColor ? favoriteColor : garageColor ? garageColor : 'red'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like you need to use double equals signs in your if statement. Use == when checking for equality. Try this:

```
car.color = favoriteColor || "red";
if (car.color == favoriteColor ){ 
    alert("your car is " + favoriteColor);

} else if (car.color == garageColor){
    alert("your car is " + garageColor);

} else {
    car.color = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will be useful

```
function _showFavColor(getColor){
 var favoriteColor = 'red';
 var garageColor  ="blue";   
 var carColor = getColor;

if (carColor == favoriteColor ){ 
    alert("your car is " + favoriteColor);

} else if (carColor == garageColor){
    alert("your car is " + garageColor);

} else {
    carColor = "red";
}
}
_showFavColor('red');
_showFavColor('blue');
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c57da150/)

Also take a note on how eqality check is done in js. You can follow this links or google it
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Also if you use car.color and if dont create the car object it will throw an error

```
 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . '
```